# python setuptools install with dynamic configuration in setup.py

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Is it possible to use dynamic configuration in a setup.py?

I have a python app which is a collection of scripts to make requests to a backend api. I would like to dynamically customise the scripts which are installed, possibly by passing a flag to the `pip install` command.

An example setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
  name='my-app',
  version='0.0.1',
  packages=find_packages(),
  scripts=['bin/do_stuff',
           'bin/do_other_stuff'
  ],
)
```

I would like to dynamically modify the contents of 'scripts', to add additional paths, based on an install flag.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip allows to pass non-standard parameters to setup.py via `--install-option` but you have to remove the param from sys.argv before calling `setup()`. So you best be is to pass additional info via environment variables:

```
MY_EXTRA_INFO=add_script pip install
```

Get the var in setup.py:

```
if 'MY_EXTRA_INFO' in os.environ:
    add_scripts = ['bin/add_script']
else:
    add_scripts = []

setup(
  scripts=['bin/do_stuff',
           'bin/do_other_stuff'
  ] + add_scripts,
)
```

Comment: Great, thanks - and how can I pass the condition to `pip install`

Comment: I extended the answer.